# c# comboBox updated by array in a method

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to C#. 
I trying to create a Combo Box that displays numbers from 1-100 generated from the method below. I am using an example that found on the internet and modifying it to meet my needs.

I can't get my combo box to display anything. Please offer suggestions or a better way to execute my intended goal.

```
 private void Range()
    {
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            arr.Add(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you adding them to an `ArrayList`, then, instead of a `ComboBox`?

Comment: I need the dropdown to display the value of 1-100. I figure an array would be an efficient way to go.

Comment: Well, the problem is obvious. Your code above actually does not even deal with a combobox at all. Do you expect your code to magically read your mind and morph into something you think it should do?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
            }`

Comment: `comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Cast<object>().ToArray());`

Comment: @RufusL I tried this. It did not work. Nothing appears in dropdown. 

   private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
            }
           
        }

Comment: If your combobox is (still) empty, comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged will never be called. I mean, how can the selection in a combobox change if there are no items in the combobox (yet) which can be selected/deselected, no?

Comment: Why would you put that code in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event? Are there any items in the combo box to start with? If not, then the selected index will never change and the event won't fire.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void FillInComboBox(ComboBox target, int start, int end)
        {
            for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            {
                target.Items.Add(i);
            }
        }
```

Usage

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillInComboBox(comboBox1, 0, 100);
        }
```

Comment: Did you create an FillInComboBox and Load from the tool box? 

I implemented what you suggested but the dropdown is still not populating.

Comment: @user716255 Double-click the form to auto-generate the `Form_Load` event.